# Displaying dict keys from users input

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to do some CLI/text based shopping program which has predefined dictionary for products.(includes product name,quantity,price)

Half of it done but having some problems with "Search" option.

Basically I have a Menu that has 5 options.

1. Search Product
2. Go to basket(shopping basket)
3. Buy
4. Logout
5. Exit

If user selects 1 / Search Product => Program should ask user to provide search terms such as water,juice,apple etc. For ex if user provides water as an input program should display everything that contains water in it with prices and list them numerically.

Lets say we have this predefined dictionary.

```
inventory = {"Rose water": [10,5], "Salty water": [5,10], "Apple": [3,10], "Sugary water": [1,5], "Cream": [5,6]}
```

**Keys in dict =** Product names

**Values in dict =** First value is Quantity, second value is Price

**For ex :**

```
 search = water

 found = Found 3 similar products 

    1. Rose water 5$

    2. Salty water 10$

    3. Sugary water 5$
```

What path should I follow? I'm trying to do this with only functions/def. Should I try class? Cuz I'm kinda stuck at searching and adding products to the basket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the limitation with dictionary is that you cannot "directly" search for partial key in a dictionary. You will have to loop through them to find out. There are alternate ways to do it and you can learn them as you advance in your learning process.

## search partial key using loop through keys

For now, you can loop through the dictionary using a list comprehension and search for the partial key in each of the keys. If found, you can pick the price and display. Before you display, you want to ensure that the quantity is greater than zero (0).

Here's how to do it.

```
inventory = {"Rose water": [10,5],
             "Salty water": [5,10],
             "Apple": [3,10],
             "Sugary water": [1,5],
             "Cream": [5,6]}

search = 'water'

#search each key in the inventory for word containing partial key search
#if found, ensure there are enough quantity to purchase
#if both conditions are satisfied, store key and price into results
results = [[key,value[1]] for key, value in inventory.items() if search.lower() in key.lower() and value[0] > 0]

#if results list contains any values, then print the details
if results:
    print ('Found', len(results), 'similar products')

    #iterate thru the results list and print the product name and price
    for i,(k,v) in enumerate(results):
        print ('    {}. {} {}$\n'.format(str(i+1),str(k),str(v)))

#if no values found in results, display product not found
else:
    print ('No products found for', search)
```

Here, Sugary water has 1 item. Your search result will be:

```
search = water

Found 3 similar products
    1. Rose water 5$

    2. Salty water 10$

    3. Sugary water 5$
```

search = water and Sugary water = 0 quantity available.

```
inventory = {"Rose water": [10,5],
             "Salty water": [5,10],
             "Apple": [3,10],
             "Sugary water": [0,5],
             "Cream": [5,6]}
```

Output will be:

```
Found 2 similar products
    1. Rose water 5$

    2. Salty water 10$
```

If search = milk, it is not found in the inventory so you will get a different message.

search = milk

Output will be:

```
No products found for milk
```

## using pandas search option

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(inventory,orient='index')
df.columns = ['Quantity', 'Price']
print (df)

#with filter option
print (df.filter(like='water', axis=0))

#with lambda function
print (df[df.index.map(lambda x: 'water' in x)])

#with search loop of df.index
print (df[['water' in s for s in df.index]])
```

The output of this will be:

Your full dataframe will be:

```
              Quantity  Price
Rose water          10      5
Salty water          5     10
Apple                3     10
Sugary water         0      5
Cream                5      6
```

Your search result for `water` will be:

```
              Quantity  Price
Rose water          10      5
Salty water          5     10
Sugary water         0      5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the dictionary and check if the inputted value is in the product name, using the `in` keyword.

Something like this code:

```py
theInput = "water"
inventory = {"Rose water": [10,5], "Salty water": [5,10], "Apple": [3,10], "Sugary water": [1,5], "Cream": [5,6]}

# Use something like below line
output = [[i, inventory[i]] for i in inventory if theInput.lower() in i.lower()]

print(output)
```

How to format the output:

```
print("found = Found %i similar products" %len(output))
for each in output:
    print("%i. %s %i$\n" %(output.index(each)+1, each[0], each[1][1]))
```

Comment: I got the point thank you so much i appreciate but as far as i know (as a beginner) i can't use index for dictionary. So do i need to convert dict into a list to use the index?

Comment: @animoxl you have, exactly. Or use a `collections.OrderedDict` instead.

Comment: @animoxl, tiny typo, x.index was supposed to be output.index

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the inventory dictionary by key, and print out items that contain the search in them.

```
search = "water"
inventory = {"Rose water": [10,5], "Salty water": [5,10], "Apple": [3,10], "Sugary water": [1,5], "Cream": [5,6]}

match = []

for key in inventory:
  if search in key:
    match.append([key, inventory[key][1]])

print("found = Found", len(match), "similar products")
for i in range(len(match)):
  print(i+1, match[i][0], str(match[i][1])+'$')
```

Using a loop, you can check the key of values in the dictionary. If search is `in` the item name. Then we use a loop to print out the items with a certain format.